# Python get the size of float number

Tags: python, numbers, size

I need to detect the actual size of int and float numbers, to verify, if it would fit into a char/short/int/long/longlong  or float/double/... types of other languages like c, Java, etc.

For int types it is easy, at least for unsigned numbers

```
   length = math.ceil(intNumber.bit_length()/8)
```

Is there a similar method for floats?

Comment: You can use `sys.getsizeof(val)` for getting size in bytes ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. 3.54456665443456687 consumes more bytes than 665456677.5

Comment: @JustMe how did you get `665456677.5`? Not to mention that it most definitely DOES NOT consume 600 MB.

Comment: @matszwecja They probably meant `sys.getsizeof(665456677.5)` should be smaller than `sys.getsizeof(3.54456665443456687)` (which isn't correct).

Comment: @Timus Yes, that is actually the problem, just vice versa. sys.getsizeof(665456677.5) is larger than sys.getsizeof(3.54456665443456687), which I did not expect.

Comment: @JustMe for me both return 24.

Comment: I think in CPython floats are build via C doubles. It uses 8 bytes for a float. You can check by `import ctypes; print(ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_double))`.